# Bootcamp with no sound or BSOD

Tags: bootcamp, audio, hdmi

1. I have downloaded latest W10 from
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
2. I used MacOS app "Boot camp" in mac to create USB installer with
   automatically downloaded latest drivers.
3. Windows installation worked OK, but without sound from HDMI (I use MacMini 2012 as HTPC).
4. When I installed Boot camp drivers (setup.exe) from USB installer, next time after restart I had constant BSOD.

ps. I tried resetting PRAM. Before installing drivers, I looked to device manager - no conflicts there (but no HDMI sound device). I tried to uninstall/reinstall audio drivers without any luck. Pls help.

Comment: add the link to the exact version of boot camp drivers you used to your question. Also if you remove the audio devices in Windows device manager and check the box to uninstall drivers and reboot, do things come back to normal?

Comment: Actually I finally get Boot camp drivers version 6 which is OK. So now I have actual windows with up to date drivers, but still no HDMI sound. I tried uninstall drivers and reboot, I tried to disable, I tried another Intel HD audio drivers. Nothing worked :/